# Can't removes duplicates from json file

Tags: javascript, json, fs

Here,I am trying to remove duplicates from my json file, so for that I tried to loop over data and remove repetitive from it.
so for that I have written this code: `

```
var newData = [];
for (i = 0; i < playerData.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < playerData[i].allTeams.length; j++) {
    for (k = 0; k < playerData[i].allTeams[j].listOfPlayer.length; k++) {
      for (s = k + 1; s < playerData[i].allTeams[j].listOfPlayer.length; s++) {
        if (
          playerData[i].allTeams[j].listOfPlayer[k].name ==
            playerData[i].allTeams[j].listOfPlayer[s].name &&
          playerData[i].allTeams[j].listOfPlayer[k].playerURL ==
            playerData[i].allTeams[j].listOfPlayer[s].playerURL
        ) {
          delete playerData[i].allTeams[j].listOfPlayer[s].name;
          delete playerData[i].allTeams[j].listOfPlayer[s].playerRole;
          delete playerData[i].allTeams[j].listOfPlayer[s].playerURL;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  newData.push(playerData[i]);
}`
```

first of all I tried to use this code in my sample data and it successfully work, but when I run this code for huge amount of data which is in file main.json then it is not working.
what stopping me from this??

**here is link of the the code and data:** https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-dewdney-40jw5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Did not find `json` data in the above link. Please share a sample `json` data.

Comment: Yasin, You must vote for the solution that worked for you.

Comment: here is sample link: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-dewdney-40jw5?file=/src/sample.json

Comment: Yasin, Fine but now you have the code help to move ahead with.

Comment: Yasin, there are a few answers to choose from here. Did any of them solve your question? If so, please mark one as the answer. if not, please respond with further clarification. Thanks

Comment: this all solution works in sample json where there is only one club and one team, but none of them works in main json where there are more then one clubs and teams.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your `json` data in the `js` variable `players`. This should work for you.

```js
var newData = [];

function removeDuplicates() {

  // Create an array of objects
  players = [{
      name: "James",
      playerrole: "Bjarne",
      playerURL:"Captain"
    },
    {
     name: "James",
      playerrole: "Bjarne",
      playerURL:"Captain"
    },
    {
      name: "James",
      playerrole: "Bjarne",
      playerURL:"Captain"
    },
    {
      name: "James",
      playerrole: "Bjarne",
      playerURL:"Captain"
    }
  ];

  jsonObject = players.map(JSON.stringify);
  uniqueSet = new Set(jsonObject);
  newData = Array.from(uniqueSet).map(JSON.parse);

  console.log(newData);

}
```

```html
<p>
  Click on the button to remove the duplicates in the array
</p>

<p>Check the console for the output</p>

<button onclick="removeDuplicates()">
  Click here
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `map()` to iterate and `.filter()` to filter out duplicates. Here is a testable snippet using your `sample.json` data

```js
const playerData = [{
  "clubName": "ADSK Cricket Club",
  "clubUrl": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewInternalClub.do?internalClubId=32&clubId=1755",
  "allTeams": [{
      "teamName": "Afgan Zalmi",
      "teamURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewTeam.do?teamId=393&clubId=1755",
      "listOfPlayer": []
    },
    {
      "teamName": "Autodesk CC",
      "teamURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewTeam.do?teamId=376&clubId=1755",
      "listOfPlayer": [{
          "name": "AMARNATH AMARNATH",
          "playerRole": " All Rounder ",
          "playerURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewPlayer.do?playerId=893120&clubId=1755"
        },
        {
          "name": "AMARNATH AMARNATH",
          "playerRole": " All Rounder ",
          "playerURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewPlayer.do?playerId=893120&clubId=1755"
        },
        {
          "name": "AMITH RAUL",
          "playerRole": " All Rounder ",
          "playerURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewPlayer.do?playerId=885821&clubId=1755"
        },
        {
          "name": "ASHISH ASHISH",
          "playerRole": " All Rounder ",
          "playerURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewPlayer.do?playerId=893119&clubId=1755"
        },
        {
          "name": "HARPREET KHAIRA",
          "playerRole": " All Rounder ",
          "playerURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewPlayer.do?playerId=885820&clubId=1755"
        },
        {
          "name": "HEMANT MURARKA",
          "playerRole": " All Rounder ",
          "playerURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewPlayer.do?playerId=885822&clubId=1755"
        },
        {
          "name": "HERSHAL K",
          "playerRole": " All Rounder ",
          "playerURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewPlayer.do?playerId=943445&clubId=1755"
        },
        {
          "name": "VISHAL PHIRANI",
          "playerRole": " All Rounder ",
          "playerURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewPlayer.do?playerId=885851&clubId=1755"
        },
        {
          "name": "IMRAN SYED",
          "playerRole": " All Rounder ",
          "playerURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewPlayer.do?playerId=839822&clubId=1755"
        },
        {
          "name": "VISHAL PHIRANI",
          "playerRole": " All Rounder ",
          "playerURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewPlayer.do?playerId=885851&clubId=1755"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
const nplayerData = playerData.map( set => {
set.allTeams = set.allTeams.map( p => {
p.listOfPlayer = p.listOfPlayer.filter((t, i, s) =>
    i === s.findIndex((pl) => (
      pl.name === t.name && pl.playerURL.trim() === t.playerURL.trim()
    ))
  );
return p;
})
return set
})
console.log(nplayerData);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this both functions:**

**getUniqueListBy(arr, key)**: Unique values from of objects, and you can specify the key

**getRemoveNestedDuplicates()**: Traverse the Nested values

```js
const playerData = [
  {
    "clubName": "ADSK Cricket Club",
    "clubUrl": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewInternalClub.do?internalClubId=32&clubId=1755",
    "allTeams": [
      {
        "teamName": "Afgan Zalmi",
        "teamURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewTeam.do?teamId=393&clubId=1755",
        "listOfPlayer": []
      },
      {
        "teamName": "Autodesk CC",
        "teamURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewTeam.do?teamId=376&clubId=1755",
        "listOfPlayer": [
          {
            "name": "AMARNATH AMARNATH",
            "playerRole": " All Rounder ",
            "playerURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewPlayer.do?playerId=893120&clubId=1755"
          },
          {
            "name": "AMARNATH AMARNATH",
            "playerRole": " All Rounder ",
            "playerURL": "https://cricclubs.com/baca/viewPlayer.do?playerId=893120&clubId=1755"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]


function getUniqueListBy(arr, key) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    return [...new Map(arr.map(item => [item[key], item])).values()]
  }
  return []
}

function getRemoveNestedDuplicates(data) {
  for (prop in data) {
    if (typeof(data[prop]) == 'object') {
      if (data[prop] && data[prop].listOfPlayer) {
        data[prop].listOfPlayer = getUniqueListBy(data[prop].listOfPlayer, 'name')
      } 
      getRemoveNestedDuplicates(data[prop])
    }
  }
}

getRemoveNestedDuplicates(playerData)


for (const data of playerData) {
  console.log(data.allTeams[1].listOfPlayer)
}
```